# How to iterate through a set of database results in AJAX

Tags: mysql, ajax, loops

problems iterating through a set of MYSQL data using AJAX. I can display the first record but there are 7 record in total. I tried couple of approaches with no success.

THe AJAX script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
      $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#btn_get').on('click', function(e) { 
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false, 
            url: 'testData.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(info){  
              $('#getdiv').html("Page Viewed:" + info[0].page_ur + "<br />" + "Page count: " + info[0].page_count + "<br />");
                console.log(info);

                var len = info.length;
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
                {$('#getdiv2').html("<br />"+" Page Viewed:" + info[i].page_ur );}


             }           
          });
          e.preventDefault();
          });         
      });                  
    </script>
```

results from console.log(info);

**console.log(info)**

```
[{page_ur:"test record page1", page_count:"1"}, {page_ur:"test record page2", page_count:"4"}, {page_ur:"test record page3", page_count:"3"}, {page_ur:"test record page5", page_count:"7"}, {page_ur:"test record page4", page_count:"9"}, {page_ur:"test record page6", page_count:"6"}, {page_ur:"test record page7", page_count:"2"}]
```

Comment: that is an arrray, so what is the problem?

Comment: #getdiv2 will end up showing only the last page_ur.  Do you want to see all the page_ur values in that div?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, you should use `.append()` instead of `.html()` so that you aren't overwriting the content during each iteration.

```
for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    $('#getdiv2').append("<br />"+" Page Viewed:" + info[i].page_ur );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the contents of #getdiv2 each time through the loop.  Try storing the markup in a variable and passing it to `$('#getdiv2').html()` after you've finished iterating over `info`.

```
var len = info.length;
var markup = '';

for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    markup += '<br/> Page Viewed:' + info[i]_page_ur;        
}
$('#getdiv2').html(markup);
```